# Emmet no sirve en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, emmet

Tengo un problema con emmet en VSC, en mis archivos HTML específicamente en la etiqueta script no me funciona la suggestion para agregar métodos rápidamente, ya probé en archivos .js y me va muy bien y de echo hasta comprobé en archivos .php y si me lanza todos sus métodos, leí documentación, busque en google, busque videos y no logre solucionarlo. Además también edite algunas cosas en el JSON y nada.

Adjunto imágenes...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Arturo, tal y como está redactada la pregunta, necesita información adicional para que podamos ayudarte. En particular, sería interesante que compartieses la configuración que tienes de Emmet, para ver si hay algo que no esté correcto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en esta línea:

```
<script type="text/babel ">
```

Tienes un espacio en blanco luego del tipo, debería quedar así:

```
<script type="text/babel">
```

Al no reconocer el tipo, emmet no sabe que sugerir.

A veces también el comportamiento de emmet se ve afectado debido a VSC desactualizado o extensiones como las intellisense y django.